# Inconsistent data in Cassandra when one node is downed and restarted

Tags: cassandra

I have an issue like this: I have 3 nodes Node1/Node2/Node3 in cassandra. When node Node1 is downed, I delete all rows one by one (just delete not truncate) and after that I pull 100k rows into cassandra. When I wakeup Node1, data of Node1/Node2/Node3 always increase. How should I fix this to make data be synchronized between nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run a repair after a node was down. Here is an explanation regarding consistency http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Consistency